# Remote connection to SQL Server 2005. "Login failed for user" or at least SEND information to other computers through WinForm app?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, connection

I have a program that installed a server (SQL Server 2005 it seems). I have patiently read quite an amount of documentation on debugging a remote connection to SQL Server 2005 but I cannot reach an end point without your help. Also I'm running out of time..

Anyway here are the details:

- Program that needs to access SQL: WinForm application
- Firewalls status: Antivir Firewall and Router Firewall off (for the moment)
- IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.2
- SQL Server 2005 with Management Studio Express,

Code I use to access the server:

```
sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=GEN; password=asd; Network Address =
192.168.1.2\\SERVER_INSTANCE; Trusted_Connection = yes; "database=DATABASE_NAME; 
connection timeout=30");

try {sqlConnection.Open();}
catch(Exception c)  {aTimer.Stop(); MessageBox.Show(c.ToString());}
```

Posting an image below with useful info from the server program:

[image]

**EDIT:** Since there doesn't seem to be many solutions, I'm also open to suggestions if I can **SEND** information from the WinForm on the Server, to other computers in the LAN

**EDIT** Attempting to upgrade the SQL Server version. (Seems that my 2005 version is not SP4.. so says the 2012 version when upgrading)

Comment: You are using a Trusted_Connection which means the user account who is running the application must also have SQL server access. Is that the case?

Comment: @Jason The person that will launch the application must connect remotly to this server. I don't really know if trusted connection helps or not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login failed for user, means that it is actually able to connect to SQL Server, but it is being denied access. Usually this is because of an incorrect username/password combination or a lack of required permissions.

Check SQL Server permissions for the desired user (If you are using windows auth).

Furthermore, SQL Server logins are not the same as Windows users. When it asks for server authentication you must login using a user created in SQL Server, not a Windows user.

Comment: When I connect locally using Windows Authentification my UserName is shown in gray as: COMPUTER_NAME\GEN (GEN is my username, and of course my administrator account). I tried both using the username with and without the computer name in front, and also checked the password by logging into Windows from standby. The password IS: asd

Comment: I have looked in Server permissions and if I check any checkboxes it doesn't remember what I checked. The only one checked is sa at Connect to SQL. I cannot make it memorise for my user as well. Also I can't use sa either to connect using SQL Server Authentification, it says the same error. As the image shows sa shouldn't have any password

Comment: Try creating the connection string using: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1409.how-to-create-a-sql-connection-string-for-an-application-udl-file.aspx

Comment: It was useful. I can test easier if the inserted info works, but it still won't accept a specific user name and password, it would work only with NT integrated security. I've even tried removing the password and using blank password and still won't work. (the username I used is the same as the one it provided with NT Integrated security). Oh yeah.. the error. It says: "Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Login failed for used 'COMP_NAME\GEN' "

Comment: SQL Server logins are not the same as Windows users. When it asks for server authentication you must login using a user created in SQL Server, not a Windows user. So your connection string should look something like "Password=password;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Initial Catalog=database;Data Source=servername" when logging on with a specific username and password.

Comment: I just tested everything. IT WORKS! Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the BEST ANSWER EVER :D

Comment: Edited this answer, it sufficiently answered the above question without needing another new answer.